# jQuery AJAX call removes empty array

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

I am writing an AJAX call in jQuery and the call invokes two functions seen below:

```
_remove: function(){
    if (confirm('Are you certain you wish to permanantly remove item from this device?')){ 
    var response = $conn.ajax({
        url: "api_url",
        async: true,
        method: "POST",
        data: this._getPayload(),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response;
    });
    }
  }



  _getPayload: function(){
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('i_host[id]', refId);
    formData.append("i_host[ipv4addrs][][del][]", "xx.x.xxx.xxx");
    return formData;
  }
});
```

I can make calls in postman with a successful set of parameters:

```
i_host[id] = refId
i_host[ipv4addrs][][del][] = xx.x.xxx.xxx
```

also, the JSON object for parameters looks like this:

```
"parameters": {
        "i_host": {
            "id": "refId",
            "ipv4addrs": [
                {
                    "del": [
                        "xx.x.xxx.xxx"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

However, the issue seems to arise when I make the jQuery call to update the API, my logs seem to accept the correct set of parameters and then give me an error with the incorrect set of parameters (it looks like the ipv4addrs is being accepted as an array of objects and then errors out as a single object). It seems that the first empty array is being removed from the call.

Any help with two functions would be great. Or any input on how to make the ajax call would also be super helpful. Logs below:

```
[DEBU|#   28|2018-08-08 14:56:44] : {"target"=>"update", "object"=>"i_hosts", "controller"=>"api", "i_host"=>{"id"=>"refId", "ipv4addrs"=>[{"del"=>["xx.x.xxx.xxx"]}]}, "action"=>"autoproxy"}
[DEBU|#   28|2018-08-08 14:56:44] : /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/
[DEBU|#   28|2018-08-08 14:56:44] : {"i_host"=>{"id"=>"refId", "ipv4addrs"=> [{"del"=>["xx.x.xxx.xxx"]}]}}
[DEBU|#   28|2018-08-08 14:56:44] : =========================================================================================
[DEBU|#   28|2018-08-08 14:56:45] : =========================================================================================
[DEBU|#   28|2018-08-08 14:56:45] : {"response":{"status":false,"message":"Please check the errors array for detailed information on why your request failed to complete!","errors":[{"messages":["The passed value does not meet the mininum required standards"],"parameters":{}}],"data":{},"parameters":{"i_host":{"id":"refId","ipv4addrs":{"del":["xx.x.xxx.xxx"]}}}}}
[DEBU|#   28|2018-08-08 14:56:45] : =========================================================================================
```

Comment: I don't understand. You're sending `del`, but the first log message says `add`. Where is that coming from?

Comment: Sorry, I have an add and del. I thought I changed them all to del. I copied the logs when I was testing an add. Turns out, ajax won't send empty arrays so I have to figure something else out.

Comment: You're sending a `FormData` object (which implies the "multipart/form-data" content-type), not JSON (which requires an "application/json" content-type). That may be the issue you're having. Also, this is likely an issue with the server-side code, which you've not shown.

Comment: **It seems that the first empty array is being removed from the call.** There's no empty array in the JSON object you show, so what does this refer to? The problem you're seeing is that a level of nesting is being removed. Do you mean the empty `[]` index? Try changing that to `[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax doesn't support empty arrays :(

Comment: While this may or may not be true, it is generally better to reference a standard that states the same...

Comment: Sorry, @HereticMonkey. At least, there was a bug found at https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10292 

I am not sure if they managed to fix it or not

Comment: Actually, that's a duplicate of https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6481#comment:12, where they say they are not going to fix it, since there's no way to represent an empty array in a x-www-form-urlencoded format. Use JSON if you want to represent structures like that.